# SQL Server login failed on linked server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

In my **SQL Server** version 15.0.4312.2, I linked another SQL Server same version. The servers are in the same **Active Directory Domain**.

Unfortunately, I get a lot of errors because apparently one server can't communicate with the other and the errors I get are:

> SQLServer Error: 16389 Communication link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01]
>
> SQLServer Error: 10004 Communication link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01]
>
> SQLServer Error: 16389 Communication link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01]
>
> Waiting for SQL Server to recover database 'msdb'...

[image]

When I test the connection from the Microsoft SQL Server Management (SSMS), the error is

> The test connection to the linked server failed.
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

[image]

I ran the `sp_linkedservers` and the result is

[image]

I tried to recreate multiple times the linked server with the same result. If I look at the properties of the linked server, there are pretty standard.

- General

[image]

- Security: be made using the login's current security context

[image]

- Server options

[image]

Also, I checked in the *Component Service* the *Local DTC Properties* and enabled everything without success.

[image]

Any ideas how can I fix this issue?

Comment: I suggest you replace you pictures with actual text where possible. The obvious "Pragmatic" solution to this is to use SQL Authentication. Although that is generally discouraged

Comment: `Be made using the login's current security context` means exactly that. If you are logged in to the local server using SQL Authentication then it will use that server's service account to attempt to connect to the linked server. Which means that it will probably fail (service accounts are usually machine-level only). Your options are: Use Windows Authentication to login to the local server. Or change the local server's service account to an AD Group Managed Service Account which has permissions on the linked server. .....

Comment: .... Or use SQL Authentication to login to the linked server (using `Be made using this security context`) or with a login mapping.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I added the images where there was some text just to clarified from where the text is coming from.